# Printing bash read input character to terminal

Tags: bash, read

Does the bash `read` command always print the user input on terminal or would I print it myself using `echo`.

For instance I do  `read -n 1 repl` inside a `while do` loop, reading each character every time.

Answer (score 0):

The `read` command does not print any input (it can print a prompt if you use that option). What you do with the input is your choice.

If you are typing the input at a terminal, the terminal driver prints what you type (but this can be reconfigured with `stty`).

If you are reading from a pipe or a file, having read print everything it received would be intolerable.